# How the execution order of interrupt is working in this program?

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt

I was reading the implementation of interrupt in Java, but I could not figure out how the control is flowing?

The code snippet is:

```
public class Main implements Runnable
{

 Thread t;

 Main() 
{
  t = new Thread(this);
  t.start();
  t.interrupt();  
  if (!t.interrupted())
  {
  System.out.println("TRUE");
  }
}

 public void run() 
 {
  try 
  {   
   System.out.println("Thread is in running state");
   Thread.sleep(1000);

  } 
  catch (InterruptedException e) 
  {
   System.out.print(t.getName() + " interrupted");
  }
 }

 public static void main(String args[]) 
{
  new Main();
 }
}
```

As per my understanding, by seeing the executing order in constructor it should be:

```
Thread is in running state
Thread-0 interrupted
TRUE
```

But this is WRONG.

The correct output is:

```
TRUE
Thread is in running state
Thread-0 interrupted
```

So please explain how this execution order work and why?

---

**Edit 1:**
As pointed out that calling `t.interrrupted()` is misleading so I changed the constructor to:

```
 Main() 
{
  t = new Thread(this);
  t.start();
  t.interrupt();  
  if (!Thread.interrupted())
  {
  System.out.println("TRUE");
  }
}
```

So now the output is:

```
TRUE
Thread is in running state
Thread-0 interrupted
```

Now the questions are,

> 1. Since the thread is in the non-runnable state when t.interrupt() was called, then what does t.interrupt() do in that case?
> 2. Why the last line of output is printed? From where does it get interrupt, because t.interrupt was executed when the thread was in the non-runnable state.

Answer (score 3):

First, you are calling the wrong method.

As pointed out in another answer, `interrupted()` is a static method that always checks the *current* thread's interrupt status. If you want to check `t`'s status, you should call `t.isInterrupted()`.

Second, you have to remember that `start()` does not guarantee that the thread begins execution immediately. In fact, that will rarely happen. The new thread will only actually begin execution when the scheduler tells it to do so.

So, what is happening is:

- you are calling `start()`, but the thread isn't actually starting yet
- you are checking the wrong thread, since the current thread obviously isn't interrupted
- the new thread starts running and is immediately interrupted due to the earlier `interrupt()` call

As for the answers to the EDIT:

- you corrected the construct, but in the wrong way. It still checks the *current* thread, which is not getting interrupted
- the last line is printed since the new thread *does* get interrupted, so when it starts it has its interrupted flag on - it immediately throws the exception

Comment: Earlier interrupt() was called when the thread was in the non-runnable stage. So it set the internal interrupt flag in Java to true. In the next line, when !Thread.interrupted() was called, then it reset the internal interrupt flag to false and printed TRUE. **But then why does it print the line, "Thread-0 interrupted"?** From where does it get interrupt then? Please clarify. I am a bit confused with this concept.

Comment: `!Thread.interrupted` does not *reset* anything. It merely tells you that the *current* thread is not interrupted. Since your thread code is entirely wrapped in a try-catch block, the moment it starts executing (and the interrupted flag is on) it immediately throws an exception.

Comment: `t.isInterrupted()` tells whether thread is interrupted or not. But `Thread.interrupted()` changes the interrupt status to false and after that returns false. Source: https://www.javatpoint.com/interrupting-a-thread

Comment: Yes, but that is not relevant to this case since `Thread.interrupted()` refers to the *current* thread, which is not being interrupted, so there's nothing to clear.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (!t.interrupted())
```

This line is misleading. `interrupted()` is a static method that checks if the *current* thread has been interrupted, not the named thread. It would be a lot better if it were written:

```
if (!Thread.interrupted())
```